# Resize original image in Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

Paperclip stores original images in "original" folder. Is there a way to resize the original images? I want to make the originals smaller in order to save the disc space.

So, for example, if visitor uploads a photo with 2592x1936 I want to store it as 1024x1024, the same way we set the dimensions for :thumb images in :styles

**Update (solved)**

I found out how to resize original images automatically on upload. One just needs to add **:original** to styles:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :photo, 
        :styles => { :original => "1024x1024>", :thumb => "150x150>" }
end
```

Comment: Wish I'd thought of that. Thanks.

Comment: As for details about the resize syntax in ImageMagick, you can find some more details here : http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#resize

Comment: I +1'd you. but I wish I could do that twice. one for the question and one for the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure paperclip does resizing by itself. You might have to look at Rmagick to get this done. I would try to get RMagick going (or [minimagick](https://github.com/probablycorey/mini_magick)) and then use a before_save callback to execute a `:resize` method that you write that tells RMagic to resize the image. Your method might look like:

```rb
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
  before_save :resize

  def resize
    self.image = self.image.resize "1024x1024"
  end
end
```

or

```rb
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
  before_save do
    self.image = self.image.resize "1024x1024"
  end
end
```

Comment: Caley Woods, thank you for your answer, but I wanted to know if there is a way to resize the original image with just Paperclip. It does resizing when it creates the :thumb images, maybe there is a way to resize the :original as well.

Comment: With that in mind you might just need to fork paperclip and modify the source to make the :original be of a size you want. This is why open source is great.

Comment: Also Evgeny as pointed out in [this asciicast](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip) you'll need imagemagick to do the resizing provided by paperclip in the format of ```has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :small => "150x150>" }``` and you'll want to [read here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry) also as this points out what characters you can use after your size call to deal with aspect ratios.